# Ffmpeg does not correctly defines FPS

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I have 2 videofiles with different resolution CIF(352*288) and D1(704*576), both with 6fps.
When converting video with CIF resolution duration is 15:00.
And when converting video with D1 resolution duration is 3:36.
I.e. ffmpeg does not understand framerate D1 video and compresses 6fps to 25fps without loss of frames.

```
Mediainfo D1 video:
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC           : No
Format settings, ReFrames        : 2 frames
Width                            : 704 pixels
Height                           : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 1.222
Standard                         : PAL
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits

Mediainfo CIF video:
Video
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : Baseline@L2.0
Format settings, CABAC           : No
Format settings, ReFrames        : 2 frames
Width                            : 352 pixels
Height                           : 288 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 1.222
Standard                         : PAL
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
```

Why? And how to fix it?

`-r 6 -filter:v "setpts=4.166*PTS"` not to offer.

I use the Google translator.

Comment: Can you explain what you need to do?  Do you need help with `ffmpeg` syntax or are you trying to determine the duration or resolution of different files?

Comment: I need to convert both video with the same parameters, with the same result.